# How to make UITextField's text selected programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I want to select all text from the UITextField selected when i start editing. I tried the below code but this doesn't work.

```
[txt selectAll:self];
```

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/clearsOnBeginEditing you should take a look at this and this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldClear:

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please check where you have placed it... Try putting the code above in

```
       -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
        {
           [textField selectAll:self];

         }
```

And also txt must be UITextField. Also do not forget to set the delegate for txt as

```
        txt.delegate = self;
```

where you have declared it and add UITextFieldDelegate in .h as

```
       @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

This will definitely work....It worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

Xyz answered correctly, but you don't necessarily need to use delegate. You may just connect action from interface builder on "Editing did begin" and write same code there.

Comment: with connection it was not working for me, but with delegate it did.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
          NSString * str = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
          return YES;}
```

when you start editing use this code to store it ur string